# Sort Javascript array of objects based of 2 values and 1 is prioritied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, sorting, methods

Hello I'm trying sort this follow data

```
[
    {
        "clockId": 27,
        "clockResetId": 2,
        "clockName": " clock1",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-05-02Z",
        "totalDays": 18,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 27
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#fe001c",
        "textColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 46,
        "clockResetId": 2,
        "clockName": "clock undenfiend",
        "station": "Dresden",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-05-02Z",
        "totalDays": 20,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 27
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#fe001c",
        "textColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 13,
        "clockResetId": 1,
        "clockName": " clock ",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "testing ",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-28Z",
        "totalDays": 22,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "tool",
        "eventDescription": "testing ",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 13
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#fe001c",
        "textColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 43,
        "clockResetId": 2,
        "clockName": " clock1",
        "station": "Braidwood",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-05-02Z",
        "totalDays": 23,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 27
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#fe001c",
        "textColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 42,
        "clockResetId": 2,
        "clockName": " clock1",
        "station": "Clinton",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-05-02Z",
        "totalDays": 28,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 27
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 49,
        "clockResetId": 2,
        "clockName": " clock undefiend",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-05-02Z",
        "totalDays": 28,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 27
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 41,
        "clockResetId": 4,
        "clockName": "clearance and tagging",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-18Z",
        "totalDays": 32,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 41
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 44,
        "clockResetId": 2,
        "clockName": " clock1",
        "station": "Dresden",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-05-02Z",
        "totalDays": 38,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 27
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 47,
        "clockResetId": 2,
        "clockName": " clock undenfiend",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-05-02Z",
        "totalDays": 38,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 27
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#f6ea00",
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    },
    {
        "clockId": 55,
        "clockResetId": 3,
        "clockName": "configuration control",
        "station": "Byron",
        "department": "",
        "owner": "",
        "type": "Non-Discretionary",
        "fleetClockGlobalRecordDays": null,
        "clockLevel": "Fleet",
        "clockDescription": "",
        "eventDate": "2020-04-01Z",
        "totalDays": 149,
        "irNum": "123",
        "observationNum": "",
        "toolToPrevent": "123",
        "eventDescription": "123",
        "clockSetter": "sarahevelynn",
        "resetHistory": [
            {
                "yearSubFour": 0,
                "yearSubThree": 0,
                "yearSubTwo": 0,
                "yearSubOne": 0,
                "maxTotalDays": 0,
                "year": 1,
                "clockId": 55
            }
        ],
        "backgroundColor": null,
        "textColor": "#000000"
    }
]
```

I need to sort by 2 values for is the `station` name in alphabetical order then after order my station name it need to order my `totalDays` is asc order

this is what I currently have

```
    clocksToDisplay = clocksToDisplay
        .sort((a: any, b: any) => {
          return a.station - b.station || a.totalDays - b.totalDays;
        })
        .map((clock: any) => {
          const details = {
            title: clock.clockName,
            info: {
              headers: ['Station', 'Status', 'Event Description'],
              labels: ['station', 'status', 'description'],
              data: [
                {
                  station: clock.station,
                  status: <img src={StatusIcon} alt="Status Icon" />,
                  description: clock.eventDescription
                }
              ]
            },
            history: {
              headers: [
                'Date Of Reset',
                'IR#',
                'Event Description',
                'Tool To Prevent Event'
              ],
              labels: ['date', 'irNum', 'description', 'toolToPrevent'],
              data: []
            }
          };
```

This is what's currently being displayed
[image]

Comment: Please, in the future, cut your data down to a more reasonable subset.  Just `clocks .map (({clockId, station, totalDays}) => ({clockId, station, totalDays}))` would give you three fields for each record, probably enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `station` is a string and not a number, the following expression in your `sort` callback will not work as expected:

```
a.station - b.station || a.totalDays - b.totalDays
```

The first half of the expression will evaluate to `NaN` and so the second half is always the determining factor of the total evaluation.

You need to compare in a "string" way:

```
a.station.localeCompare(b.station) || a.totalDays - b.totalDays
```